# Flask JWT Extended- Different locations for access_token (header) & refresh_token(httpOnly cookie)

Tags: flask-jwt-extended

How to configure flask app with flask-jwt-extended for which we need something like below.

1. AccessToken/Bearer must sent as a Header (and not cookie)
2. RefreshToken must sent as httpOnlyCookie for /api/refreshtoken path only

How to set two different token one in header and one in cookie? We are able to set either both as cookie or both as a header.

Any help?

Thanks
Raxit

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same while building a React + Flask single page application after days of headache trying to understand authorization and authentication as I am a beginner.

Anyways, I managed to do it this way:

In Flask, config:

```
app.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['headers', 'cookies']
app.config['JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/auth/refresh'
```

And what I return in my login function:

```
resp = jsonify({'access_token': access_token})
set_refresh_cookies(resp, refresh_token)
return resp, 200
```

And in my refresh function:

```
# Refresh access token
@app.route('/auth/refresh', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_refresh_token_required
def refresh():
    user = get_jwt_identity()
    resp = {
        'access_token': create_access_token(
            identity={
                'username': user['username'],
                'role': user['role']
            },
            expires_delta=timedelta(seconds=600),
            user_claims=user['role']
        )
    }
    return jsonify(resp), 200
```

And on the front side, I collect the JSON access_token and set it in memory and use withCredentials to send the refresh_token with my API calls.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
```

more precisely:

```
.then(({ data: { access_token } }) => {
      axiosHttp.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
      return jwt_decode(access_token);
    })
```

then I use the data from my decoded access_token in a React Context Component to authenticate access to pages depending on roles.

logout is simply setting to null my context and calling the api to unset the refresh cookie

```
@app.route('/auth/logout', methods=['DELETE'])
@jwt_required
def logout():
    resp = jsonify({"msg": "Successfully logged out"})
    unset_jwt_cookies(resp)
    return resp, 200
```

it's quite simple in the end but it took me quite a while to figure out!